# Newly logged in user can see previously logged in users data for a brief second

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, caching

I've deployed a basic crud MERN project where a user can login and save entries. My issue is whenever I logout and login with a new user for a brief second I can see the previous users entries then loads the correct data. Where would I start looking to solve this issue? Any advice is appreciated.

In my fetch calls I added `'Cache-Control': 'no-store'`. In nodejs I used `res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');` in my get request.

This is how my logout function looks like:

```js
    const logout = () => {
        const clearCacheData = () => {
          caches.keys().then((names) => {
            names.forEach((name) => {
              caches.delete(name);
            });
          });
        };
        clearCacheData()
        localStorage.clear()
        navigate('/auth/login', { replace: true })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logout function should navigate -- load a new browser page -- immediately  when your user chooses it. Logout functions are often implemented with old-school href links for this reason.

Your login page should clear all browser-side data before it attempts to render anything.

Or you can navigate to a logout page that clears browser-side data, then immediately navigate again to a login page.

And, if you do a fetch or xhr request from your browser code and it gets back an invalid session response (because the session token has expired or a forgery was attempted) your code should also immediately navigate to the page that clears browser-side data. (Consider the use case of a user on a public computer who walks away without logging  out.)

**Edit** In the usual course of operation for a React client-side app, it is (as you mentioned) best not to reload the web page holding the app. Reloading the web page tears down the Javascript context running the app. But, when your user logs out from your app, you owe it to them to erase their personal information from the browser they are using. The most straightforward and secure way to do that is to reload the page and rebuild the Javascript context from scratch for the next user.  So, the logout workflow is an exception to the usual advice about leaving the React app running.

Comment: So I added : window.location.href = `{path}` to my logout function and it fixed my issue. Everywhere I looked it says to not use that as it will 'bypass the benefits of client-side routing and React's virtual DOM reconciliation.' Could you please explain the reasoning as I still don't understand why useNavigate doesn't work?

Comment: Please see my edit. Reloading  the React app is a security measure.